# How to add a register form inside the login popup during the checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, ajax, register

I want to add a register form directly inside the login modal during the checkout (instead of the register link that lead to a register customer form page), so that the customer can quickly register without leaving the checkout process.
I'm aware of third party modules, i already checked this kind of solution but this modules enables a lot of features i don't want.

I have some theorical steps in mind, but i'm definitely not sure if it's the right way to do it, or even if it would work:

- override the authentication popup ui module: add a register form inside the knockout view (html template) and send via ajax the data submitted (inside the knockout viewModel or directly inside the template?) to a new page
- set up the route for the new page
- create a controller for the route
- inside the execute method of the controller, get the data submitted (getRequest()->getParam('data')) and create the account with the date using the customerFactory->create method.

If anyone could give me advices about it, that would be great :)

Thanks!